# Php Script to Opening and closing firefox navigator

Tags: php, function, firefox, exec

i try to do a php script to open and close firefox (version 24.0) automaticaly. The code is :

```
<?php
//opening firefox
exec('"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"');

//Waiting a moment to let firefox charging
sleep(20);

//Closing firefox
exec("TASKKILL /IM firefox.exe /F");
?>
```

But i have a problem, the navigator open succefully but it still opened long time until i close it manuelly and then it waiting 20 seconds and tell me that there is no processus firefox to kill.

Please i need your help as soon as possible.

Hello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that php exec() waits for the program to finish and close before continuing on in the script, [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) . In order to fix the issue, you can use a method similar to:

```
<?php 
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
} 
?>
```

(Code credit goes to Arno van den Brink, see the comments section on the linked page.)

This function determines if the OS is windows or not and uses the proper php commands to execute the program without causing php to wait for the program to close.